# Get input type file value in jQuery when it has `multiple` attribute

Tags: jquery

I have the following input type file with `multiple` attribute:

```
<input accept=".txt" id="File" multiple="" name="File" type="file" />
```

When I use jQuery to read the input value:

```
$("#File").val()
```

I selected from my PC, two files. If I call above function it returns:

```
C:\fakepath\1.txt
```

I expect to return 2 file values (I don't know, separated by comma or other separator).

Comment: The val() function return path of files separated by comma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the files property like

```
var files = $("#File").prop('files')
```

then loop it and read the name property of the file

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8a4Z2/)

Answer (score 2):

You could access the underlying DOM element:

```
var fileList = $("#File")[0].files;
for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
   // Do stuff
}
```